# Adding multiple key/values to a map without using set

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to add to a map, without using set.

Say I have a list of colors. If I used an object, it'd be as simple as:

```
var colors = {
  red: 'hsl(0,50,50)',
  green: 'hsl(150,50,50)',
  blue: hsl(210,50,50)
}
```

What is the equivalent way of doing this with a map?

I know that adding to a map is as simple as:

```
colors.set('red','hsl(0,50,50)')
```

...but that would mean I have to do it for all the colors I have in my collection. Is there a shorter way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a `Map` with an array of arrays. The second dimension has to be `[key, value]`.

```
const colors = new Map([
  ['red', 'hsl(0,50,50)'],
  ['green', 'hsl(150,50,50)'],
  ['blue', 'hsl(210,50,50)'],
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects do not natively support **[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**, though you can use it in conjunction with **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**.

You can use either the [**dot notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) or the [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) inside of `Object.keys(colors).map(function(key, index) {})`:

```js
var colors = {
  red: 'hsl(0,50,50)',
  green: 'hsl(150,50,50)',
  blue: 'hsl(210, 50, 50)'
}

Object.keys(colors).map(function(key, index) {
  colors["another"] = "value";
  colors.another2 = "value2";
});

console.log(colors);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question... I'm talking about the `Map` object, not `Array.prototype.map()`